# RxJS Emitting Subscribe Twice

Tags: rxjs

I have a RXJS function that will create an empty Observable, tap into the result and return that new observable. I want the observable to always run the tap so I noop subscribe (in the real case it might not ever be subscribed to).

```js
function that() {
  let obs = of({});
  obs = obs.pipe(tap(() => console.log('here')))
  obs.subscribe();
  return obs;
}

const res = that();
res.subscribe(() => console.log('finished'))
```

If you run this code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5h6jz), you will notice that `here` is fired twice. The output looks like this:

```
 here
 here
 finished
```

I've tried several different approaches but I can't ever seem to get it to work where it doesn't emit twice.

Answer (score 0):

You subscribe TWICE:

```
function that() {
    let obs = of({});
    obs = obs.pipe(tap(() => console.log('here')))
    obs.subscribe(); // first subscription
    return obs;
}

const res = that();
res.subscribe(() => console.log('finished')) // second subscription
```

This is the same observable you subscribe to, once in the function, then on the returned value.

Just don't subscribe in the function

```
function that() {
    let obs = of({});
    obs = obs.pipe(tap(() => console.log('here')))
    return obs;
}

const res = that();
res.subscribe(() => console.log('finished')) // subscribe from here only
```

See the updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9c2rnd).

Comment: Yes, I figured that much. How do I make it not do that and still subscribe twice?

Comment: This is a very simplified case, in the real case, I have to noop subscribe so that I ensure tap always ran.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a case of only tapping only the inner subscription?

```
function that() {
  let obs = of({});
  obs.pipe(tap(() => console.log('here'))).subscribe();
  return obs;
}

const res = that();
res.subscribe(() => console.log('finished'))
```